# executing sql inside ssis script task is not working

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, ado.net, ssis

Trying to execute the sql statement inside the vb.net (script task ssis).For this created the connections,requsted open connection and executed and closed(as shown in the below code).The value of a variable (which holds the sql result set) has to be returned a correct count,instead it returned  -1 all the times ...any idea y does it so?Seems to be the query is not executing?

how to get the correct count value using this below vb codes(please have a look)
 in ssis script task?

Public Sub Main()

```
    Dim fireAgain As Boolean = True
    Dim rowsAffected As Integer

    Dim sqlConn As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim sqlComm As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand


    Dim cm As ConnectionManager = Dts.Connections("cnn") ''Retrive the reference to the managed Connections

    '' Request an open connection
    sqlConn = cm.AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction)
    Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "", "Connection is: " + sqlConn.State.ToString(), "", 0, fireAgain)

    ''Do your work

    sqlComm = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT  FROM [Table_1]", sqlConn)
    rowsAffected = sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery()

    MsgBox(rowsAffected.ToString())  '''' the value of variable is -1 ???

    ''Inform SSIS you're done your work
    cm.ReleaseConnection(sqlConn)

    Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "", rowsAffected.ToString() + " rows updated.", "", 0, fireAgain)



End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of affected rows by the query. In the case of the COUNT function it always returns -1.

For what you are trying to achieve, you should be using `sqlComm.ExecuteScalar()` which returns the value of the first row/column from the resultset.

Answer (score 4):

When you use `ExecuteNonQuery`, you are saying that you do not require any results back from the query.

To read the result from your query, use `ExecuteScalar`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx

If your query returns more than one cell, use `ExecuteReader` and a `SQLDataReader` object:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx